# Trigger python file under django project from a HTML button

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

My python script file in under django project but in some other folder(say, otherPythons). I want to trigger this python file on click of a HTML button using javascript.

Please no PHP

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Django doesn't care which folder your view code is in. Just define a URL that points to it.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have to trigger the python file and not just access the file for read/write operations.could you please let me know, how to do it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Why is this different from any other view?